# Problem migrating SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, sql

I currently have a SQL Server 2008 database on Windows Server 2008 and I want to move the data to a MySQL 5.1.54 database on a Ubuntu server. I downloaded the MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver, created a DSN with correct connection information, and I tried to use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to export the data. However, in the queries the wizard generated, table and column names were surrounded with `"` characters instead of the correct ` characters, so I get syntax errors when I try to execute the export. I cannot edit all of the generated SQL by hand, so is there some configuration I can change to make it use the correct quote characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate [ANSI quotes in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes).

Try to add

```
SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'
```

to your scripts.